# Replace '\\' with '\' in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Data: Input
let x = "«Pe.¯­\\x02`ä¦c\\x0E,ÞHä"

Expected Output:
«Pe.¯­\x02`ä¦c\x0E,ÞHä

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted already produces the desired string because `\\` in string literals produces `\`.

```js
let x = "«Pe.¯­\\x02`ä¦c\\x0E,ÞHä";
console.log(x);                           // «Pe.¯­\x02`ä¦c\x0E,ÞHä
```

---

But let's say you started with

```
«Pe.¯­\\x02`ä¦c\\x0E,ÞHä
```

In that case, you could use the following:

```js
let x = "«Pe.¯­\\\\x02`ä¦c\\\\x0E,ÞHä";
console.log(x);                           // «Pe.¯­\\x02`ä¦c\\x0E,ÞHä
x = x.replace(/\\\\/g, "\\");             // Replace each pair of `\` with one.
console.log(x);                           // «Pe.¯­\x02`ä¦c\x0E,ÞHä
```

Answer (score 0):

Substitution Pattern: `\\(\\)`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/rTaxgS/1